# How to refactor nested for loop?

Tags: c++, algorithm, function, for-loop, refactoring

I have two similar functions. Both functions contain a nested `for` -loop. How I can combine these two functions to decrease duplicated code.

The only difference between `funcA` and `funcB` is `funcB` calls `func_2` in the loop.

The two functions like below.

```
void funcA()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            func_1();
        }
    }
}

void funcB() 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            func_1();
            func_2();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is size in that case? is i and j needed in the inner function(s)?

Comment: You're missing to tell us more about the different use cases of calling `funcA()` and `funcB()`, under which conditions is either one called? Basically you want a parameter to merge that code into one function, and decide regarding that parameter, if `func_2()` needs to be called or not.

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < size * size; ++i) {func_1();}` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps I am taking it a little too far, but there is no apparent reason for the nested loops (neither `func_1()` nor `func_2()` depend on `i` or `j`). A straight forward way to pass a callable is the following:

```
 template <typename F>
 void func(F f) {
      for (int i=0; i < size*size; ++i) f();
 }
```

and then call either

```
 func([](){ func_1(); });
 func(&func_1);               // passing function pointer works as well
```

or

```
 func([](){ func_1(); func_2(); });
```

PS: There is a difference between the nested loops and the flat one when `size*size` can overflow or it is negative. Though passing the callable is orthogonal to that.

Comment: *"There is a difference between the nested loops and the flat one when `size*size` can overflow."* or when `size` is negative. ^_^

Comment: @Jarod42 nice catch

Comment: Won't happen with `unsigned`... (`signed`/`unsigned` war for `size`) ;-)

Comment: @Jarod42 I'd just add a `assert(size is not a misleading name)` ;)

Comment: `size_is_not_a_number`(`_as_463035818`), `size_is_not_a_variable` ;-)

Answer (score 7):

You could have used [variadic templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack).

```
template<class ... FuncTypes>
void funcAB(FuncTypes... Funcs)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        for(int j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
            (Funcs(), ...);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how to call the function.

```
funcAB(&func_1); // if you want to only call func_1
funcAB(&func_1, &func_2) // if you want both to be called
```

Comment: instead using variadic templates it is better to use lambda and pass those indexes to it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I accept lambda function to solve my issue because I am more familar with that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

You can replace it with one single [template function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template). It takes variadic arguments of functions, and each function will be called by the [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) (Since [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17)) expansion.
In addition, using the  [`ranges::views::iota`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/iota_view) (Since [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20)) you can combine the two `for`-loops to one.

Something like follows:

```
#include <ranges> // std::views::iota    

template<typename... Funcs> 
void funcAB(Funcs&&... funcs)
{
    for ([[maybe_unused]] int i : std::views::iota(0, size * size)) {
        (funcs(), ...);                
    }
}
```

You will call the `funcAB`:

```
funcAB(func1);        // for funcA() call
funcAB(func1, func2); // for funcB() call
```

### ([Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9ej85cj4j))

Comment: much thanks JeJo for your answer and kindly edit my question.  I accept lambda function to solve my issue because I am more familar with that.

Answer (score 1):

the only difference between funcA and funcB is that funcB calls **func_2();** then use a flag to control whether that method should be called or not

```
void funcC(bool shouldInvokeFunc2)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    for(int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        func_1();
        if(shouldInvokeFunc2) // use the flag
        {
            func_2();
        }     
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I would make the bool a template parameter in this case so the compiler can more easily optimize away the if statement in the inner loop

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function which accepts a function as argument but without more information this is the only example I can give:

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr int size = 1;

void func(void (*f)()) 
{
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
  {
    for(int j = 0; j < size; j++) 
    {
      f();
    }
  }
}

void func_1(){ std::cout << "func_1" << std::endl; }

void func_2(){ std::cout << "func_2" << std::endl; }

void funcA()
{
    func_1();
}

void funcB() 
{
    func_1();
    func_2();
}

int main()
{
    func(funcA);
    func(funcB);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create one function with a parameter, depending on that parameter call `func_2()`. You can also give that parameter a default value.

```cpp
void funcA(bool callFunc2 = false) {
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
      func_1();

      if (callFunc2) {
         func_2();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`funcA()` will run without calling `func_2()` and `funcA(true)` will run with the execution of `func_2()`.

Answer (score 0):

Besides different ways of passing implementations as function arguments (e.g. through lambdas or function pointers) as mentioned in the other posts, you could think of inheritance and overriding for expressing the reuse of behaviour:

```
struct Base {
    int size = 2;
    void loop() {
      for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            func();
        }
      }
    }
    virtual void func() = 0;
};

struct A : public Base {
    void func() override {
      cout << "for an A, call func1" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct B : public Base {
    void func() override {
      cout << "for a B, call func1 and func2" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    B b;
    
    a.loop();
    b.loop();
}
```

Output:

```
for an A, call func1
for an A, call func1
for an A, call func1
for an A, call func1
for a B, call func1 and func2
for a B, call func1 and func2
for a B, call func1 and func2
for a B, call func1 and func2
```

Comment: A very good answer. Thanks.